# Why is using list comprehension here so slow?

Tags: python, list

I was writing some python and needed to find the indexes of the largest numbers a list. I looked it up and found this:

```
def find_indexes_1(nums)
    return [index for index, number in enumerate(nums) if number == max(nums)]
```

After some testing, I isolated this line as the main reason my program was so slow. I decided to rewrite the code without using list comprehension.

```
def find_indexes_2(nums):
    largest = 0
    indexes = []
    for index, number in enumerate(nums):
        if number > largest:
            indexes.clear()
            indexes.append(index)
            largest = number
        elif number == largest:
            indexes.append(index)
    return indexes
```

This is much longer and harder to read but I found it to be *significantly* faster than the first method.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from random import randint

numbers = []
for i in range(10000):
    numbers.append(randint(10, 55))

start = timer()
a = find_indexes_1(numbers)
end = timer()
time = str(end-start)
print(f'method 1 {time}') # 2.087865 seconds
start = timer()
b = find_indexes_2(numbers)
end = timer()
time = str(end-start)
print(f'method 2 {time}') # 0.001524 seconds
```

my main question is why is the first method so much slower? I understand that it loops through the list twice but that doesn't justify such a large difference between the two times.
Thanks

Comment: The main problem is maxVal= max(nums) that you're calling inside the comprhension. calculate it apart and then use the compare with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `max(nums)` that is going over `nums` linearly is called `len(nums)` times. This gives you O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity in `find_indexes_1`, compared to O(n) in `find_indexes_2`

You could optimize it like this:

```
def find_indexes_3(nums)
    max_nums = max(nums) # compute this value once, takes O(n) time
    return [index for index, number in enumerate(nums) if number == max_nums]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `max(nums)` on each iteration of the list comprehension, and this has to iterate over the list again. So you have an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm. Since it doesn't change, you should call it once.

```
def find_indexes_1(nums)
    maxnum = max(nums)
    return [index for index, number in enumerate(nums) if number == maxnums]
```